# Generating Pandas Column Based on 2 Series and List

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to generate a new column in pandas that is dependent on values from two other Series in the dataframe. Was wondering what is the most efficient way to do so.

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: Tasks,Primary User, Secondary User.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Task':list('ABC'),
                   'Primary User':['Alan','Ben','Christine'],
                   'Secondary User':['Dan','Eve','Fran']})

print (df)

  Task Primary User Secondary User
0    A         Alan            Dan
1    B          Ben            Eve
2    C    Christine           Fran
```

I would like to Generate an additional series in the data called 'Username'.

The username should be derived from the list below:

```
userNames = [('Alan','alan123'), ('Ben', None), ('Christine', None), ('Dan', 'dan789'), ('Eve', 'Eve234'), ('Christine', None)]
```

The username column has only ONE username and will take the Username of the primary User, unless the primary user's `username = None` then it will pull the username of the Secondary User. If  both `users =None` then populate 'Error'.

Output should be:

[image]

I have struggling to create this if station.

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: How are generated second values in tuples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create dictionary with list of tuples, [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) first column and similar second with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace NaNs if not matched values by `Primary User`:

```
d = {k:v for k, v in userNames}
print (d)
{'Alan': 'alan123', 'Ben': None, 'Christine': None, 
  'Dan': 'dan789', 'Eve': 'Eve234', 'Fran': None}

df['Usename'] = df['Primary User'].map(d).fillna(df['Secondary User'].map(d)).fillna('Error')
print (df)
  Task Primary User Secondary User  Usename
0    A         Alan            Dan  alan123
1    B          Ben            Eve   Eve234
2    C    Christine           Fran    Error
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['Primary User'].map(d))
0    alan123
1       None
2       None
Name: Primary User, dtype: object
```